# Is this room good to grow my grapevine and longan fruit tree?

Tags: fruit-trees, grape-vine

[image]

I want the grapevine to grow decently and bear fruits. I read that it needs full direct sunlight. Should I move it outside? Also. Can you recommend fruit/veggies i can plant in this pot if  I remove the grape?

I also have longan tree here in the same room and it thrives since the last time I move it here and it receives same amount of light. But never yet bear fruits. So, is this room good condition to grow fruit?

Comment: Grapes in shade, no. Herbs can do okay in shade, ferns, impatiens, hosta, even roses, too.

Comment: You might want to add your location/USDA hardiness zone equivalent/min temperature for us to help.

Comment: Is this a seedling from a grape seed? If yes, you may be very disappointed even if you can get it to set fruit (which is likely not going to happen).